# copy() isn't working will all URLs

Tags: php, csv, import, copy

I'm facing strange issue, I'm uploading a csv file into my DB and everything is working find, all records are being imported successfully (5000 records)

One of the csv columns is a URL string and I'm using the `copy()` function to copy the image to my server so some of these URLs are being copied successfully but not all of them, although when I test the URL in my browser it's working fine but why it's not working with `copy()` function.

Here's my code:

```
$fileName = pathinfo($line[$post['wk_mpmassupload_general']['image']], PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "." . pathinfo($line[$post['wk_mpmassupload_general']['image']], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

copy($line[$post['wk_mpmassupload_general']['image']], './image/catalog/' . $fileName);
```

All URLs are working when you open in any browser and some of them are being imported successfully but not all of them.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Any number of things could be going on, including sites which don't allow you to use copy() to steal their images

Comment: @Mark Baker, all of the URLs are on the same site

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not getting anything, I will check the error log to see if there's something useful.